# Google cluster map, locations array with acf

Tags: maps, cluster-computing

i'm using the standard cluster google map found here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering

I have it working fine from the example.
I am trying to hook up acf to my cpt for long and lat to pop within the locations const array.

Instead of using the standard:

```
  const locations = [
        { lat: -33.718234, lng: 150.363181 },
        { lat: -33.727111, lng: 150.371124 },
        { lat: -33.848588, lng: 151.209834 },
        { lat: -33.851702, lng: 151.216968 },
        { lat: -34.671264, lng: 150.863657 },
        { lat: -35.304724, lng: 148.662905 },
        { lat: -36.817685, lng: 175.699196 },
        { lat: -36.828611, lng: 175.790222 },
        { lat: -37.75, lng: 145.116667 },
        { lat: -37.759859, lng: 145.128708 },
        { lat: -37.765015, lng: 145.133858 },
        { lat: -37.770104, lng: 145.143299 },
        { lat: -37.7737, lng: 145.145187 },
        { lat: -37.774785, lng: 145.137978 },
        { lat: -37.819616, lng: 144.968119 },
        { lat: -38.330766, lng: 144.695692 },
        { lat: -39.927193, lng: 175.053218 },
        { lat: -41.330162, lng: 174.865694 },
        { lat: -42.734358, lng: 147.439506 },
        { lat: -42.734358, lng: 147.501315 },
        { lat: -42.735258, lng: 147.438 },
        { lat: -43.999792, lng: 170.463352 },
      ];
```

I have this set up:

```
const locations = [
          <?php
              $args = array(
                  'post_type' => 'stockists',
                  'posts_per_page' => -1
              );
              $places = new WP_Query($args);
              if($places->have_posts()){
                  while($places->have_posts()) {
                     the_post();?>

                     {lat:<?php echo get_field('lat') ?>, lng:<?php echo get_field('long') ?>},

          <?php }} ?>
      ];
```

However I am getting these errors:

**Notice**:  Undefined offset: 15 in **/home/sites/7b/d/de4743ded0/public_html/typhoon/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php** on line **3284**
['',

I've tried conditional acf to only show populated posts, but still no luck. Only one post currently has it's long and lat in.

I need to have the long and lats in acf as user will need to import via CSV, so I can't manually add them.

Really stuck, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

My post query was slightly off and I wrapped a condition around my acf's.

```
const locations = [
              <?php
                  $args = array(
                      'post_type' => 'stockists',
                      'posts_per_page' => -1
                  );
                  $places = new WP_Query($args);
                  if($places->have_posts()){
                      while($places->have_posts()) {
                         $places->the_post(); ?>
                         <?php if (get_field('lat')) : ?>
                          {lat:<?php echo get_field('lat') ?>, lng:<?php echo get_field('long') ?>},
                         <?php endif; ?>
                  <?php } ?>
                  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
              <?php } ?>
          ];
```